# What is Best way to rerender the child component when View's Object array changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I tried this.$forceupdate() , v-if hack but it didn't work. I am new to Vue.

```
<template>
  <div class="intro-y grid grid-cols-12 gap-3 sm:gap-6 mt-5">
    <HeroCard v-for="hero in heroes" :key="hero.id" :hero="hero" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import HeroCard from "@/components/hero/HeroCard.vue";
export default {
  inject: ["heroStats"],
  name: "HeroList",
  components: {
    HeroCard,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      heroes: this.heroStats,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    filterHeroes(heroStats, primary_attribute, attack_type, roles, name) {
      if (!primary_attribute.length) {
        this.heroes = heroStats;
      } else {
        this.heroes = heroStats.filter((hero) =>
          primary_attribute.includes(hero.primary_attr)
        );
        ...etc
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

When Checkboxes are checked the HeroCard component should display heroes that including the primary attributes[ 'Strength', 'Intelligence' ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make heroes to a computed property and filter it with a `selected_attributes` data property bound to your checkboxes.

```
data() {
      return {
           heroStats: heroStats,
           selected_attributes: ['Strength', 'Intelligence']
     }
},
computed: {
   heroes() {
       return this.heroStats.filter((hero) =>
        this.selected_attributes.includes(hero.primary_attr)
       );
   }
}
```

Then the heroes list  will be auto-updated, when the checkboxes and `selected_attributes` changes. This ten will automatically trigger the update of your heroes card list.

```
 <HeroCard v-for="hero in heroes" :key="hero.id" :hero="hero" />
```

This is the simplest and most Vue style solution from my point of view.

The Vue reactivity do all the work and you don't need to trigger update of your child components.

Answer (score 0):

---

you can set a flag and when the Object Array changes set that flag to true (visa versa)
and then use a v-if to render that component only when that flag is set to true
something like

````
  <div class="intro-y grid grid-cols-12 gap-3 sm:gap-6 mt-5">
    <HeroCard v-if="showComponent" v-for="hero in heroes" :key="hero.id" :hero="hero" />
  </div>
</template>```
````